# Price per Customer in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer, price

I'm using Magento 1.9 version and i would like to set the different price per customer. Default magento comes with tier price for a customer group, i want the similar feature to set it for a specific customer. I know there are few paid plugins which achieves what i have asked for(prices are too high), but i want to achieve the same by without using any paid versions. Step by procedure is most welcomed. Thank you in advance

Comment: have u got solution for this?if yes can you share the solution.Thanks